# append things to the end of a pattern

Tags: regular-expression

I have several instances of variables in a file and I need to modify the variable and append "new" to each of the names.

```
var Modelfrfr = ....

var Modeldede = ...

var Modelenen = ...
```

change it to

```
var ModelfrfrNew = ....

var ModeldedeNew = ...

var ModelenenNew = ...
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Kind of this

```
%s/Model\a\+/&New/g
```

See `:h :s`, `:h /\a`, `:h sub-replace-special` and so on.

Comment: Maybe change `Model` to `var ` to be more generic?

Comment: @Vee That depends on use case.

Answer (score 0):

With the cursor on the first line at the first column, the command `t=<C-v>2jINew<Esc>` where:

1. `t=` moves the cursor *to* immediately before the first `=`.
2. `<C-v>` for visual block mode.
3. `2j` to select the two lines beneath.  Replace the 2 with any number or press j until the cursor has selected the desired number of lines.
4. `I` for insert mode.
5. `New` for the desired text to append to all of the variables.
6. `<Esc>` to exit insert mode and apply the text to all lines in the selection.

### Edit

In retrospect, that will only work for a solid block of variables.  If they're spaced throughout a file, maybe a macro? `qq/var<CR>eeaNew<Esc>q`

1. `qq` to start the macro in register `q`
2. `/var<CR>` to search for var.
3. `ee` to move to the end of the variable name.
4. `aNew` to append "New".
5. `<Esc>q` to exit insert mode and stop recording the macro.

Repeat with `@q` as needed.

Hope that helps!